# Saving file in pdf form in R language

Tags: r, pdf, graph, save

I want to get the output of these graphs into two seperate pdf files.
When I run the program, it generates the files, but when I open the files, it gives me the following message.
"There was an error in opening this document. The document can not be opened, because it has no pages"
Could you please tell me, what I am doing wrong?
The code is following

```
plot_graph <- function(data_frame)  
{  
require(lattice)
pdf("myplot1.pdf")
xyplot(V21 ~ V4|V1, data = data_frame)
pdf(file = "myplot2.pdf")
xyplot(V22 ~ V4|V1, data = data_frame)
dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call dev.off() for each device you open. Try

```
plot_graph <- function(data_frame) {  
  require(lattice)
  pdf("myplot1.pdf")
  print(xyplot(mpg ~ hp|gear, data = data_frame))
  dev.off()
  pdf("myplot2.pdf")
  print(xyplot(disp ~ hp| gear, data = data_frame))
  dev.off()
}
plot_graph(mtcars)
```

Comment: tried, but have the same problem @MrFlick

Comment: I've updated with a working example. You also need to explicitly `print()` lattice plots as per the [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)